# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed issue

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

i want to  learn regression problem  related to image processing techniques, therefore i found following tutorial : [Image regression](https://github.com/Thundertung/Book-Price-regression-CNNs/blob/main/Judging%20a%20book%20by%20its%20cover.ipynb)

when i  was  reading following code :

```
import numpy as np #for numerical computations
import pandas as pd #for dataframe operations
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt #for viewing images and plots
#So that Matplotlib plots don't open in separate windows outside the notebook
import urllib #For fetching data from Web URLs
import cv2   #For image processing
import urllib3
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder    #For encoding categorical variables
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #For splitting of data
#All tensorflow utilities for creating, training and working with a CNN
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
def show_image_from_url(image_url):
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(image_url)
  image = np.asarray(bytearray(response.read()), dtype="uint8")
  image_bgr = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  plt.imshow(image_rgb), plt.axis('off')
data =pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Thundertung/Book-Price-regression-CNNs/main/main_dataset.csv")
print(data.head())
# print(data['price'])
# print(data.columns)
plt.figure()
show_image_from_url(data['image'].loc[10])
plt.show()
```

i am  getting this error :

```
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 945, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 827, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

if i  try to  open link alone, i am also getting error, is this erro related to fact that page  does not exist in reality or i should change some parameters? thanks in advance